# Unable to decode a JSON with JSON Decoder

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I'm using JSON decoder to decode some Instagram users. Here's the model:

```
struct User: Decodable {

    var clear_client_cache: Int
    var has_more: Int
    var hashtags: String?
    var places: String?
    var rank_token: String?
    var status: String?
    var users: [Users]?

     struct Users: Decodable {

        var position: Int
        var user: InstaUser?

         struct InstaUser: Decodable {

            var byline: String?
            var follower_count: Int?
            var full_name: String?
            var has_anonymous_profile_picture: Int?
            var is_verified: Int?
            var mutual_followers_count: Int?
            var pk: Int?
            var profile_pic_id: String?
            var profile_pic_url: String?
            var unseen_count: Int?
            var usernam: String?

        }

    }

}

    {
    "clear_client_cache" = 0;
    "has_more" = 0;
    hashtags =     (
    );
    places =     (
    );
    "rank_token" = "3b22a104-7ac5-4052-be10-e7a7be4e67b4";
    status = ok;
    users =     (
    );
}
```

> typeMismatch(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
>   [CodingKeys(stringValue: "clear_client_cache", intValue: nil)],
>   debugDescription: "Expected to decode Int but found a number
>   instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Than I just use

```
let user = try? decoder.decode(User.self, from: response.data!)
```

It says that it wants a number, what's wrong? Sorry, maybe it's too simple, but I'm coding for 12 hours already

Comment: then try jsonSerialization

Comment: `clear_client_cache` must contain another value, probably nil

Comment: It was Bool After all... That value. I realized it by using SwiftyJSON

Comment: hehe.. the crash doesn't lie