# iOS JSON decoding number type error

Tags: json, swift, api, decodable

I'm having issues decoding banking information from an API's JSON response.

Here are the relevant parts of my data structures. I made the TransactionResponse object to simplify pulling the relevant data from the response:

```
struct Transaction: Decodable {
    ... // other properties, not relevant to this
    let isFutureDated: Float?   /\
    ... // see above ___________/
}

struct TransactionResponse: Decodable {
    let response: Response?

    struct Response: Decodable {
        ...
        let transactions: [Transaction]?
    }
}
```

And my conversion from the JSON data object:

```
do {
    let transactions = try JSONDecoder().decode(TransactionResponse.self, from: data)
} catch let localError {
    print(localError)
}
```

If I comment out the *isFutureDated* property, the object loads just fine (there's about a dozen other properties, so it's not just that it successfully loads nothing :P). When I include the *isFutureDated* property in the data structure, I catch the following error:

> typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "response", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "transactions", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "isFutureDated", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: **"Expected to decode Float but found a number instead."**, underlyingError: nil))

Am I missing something? Is a Float not a number? I've also tried changing the type for *isFutureDated* to Double, Int, Int8, Int16, Int 32, Int64, UInt, UInt8... you get the idea. Even Data and String. Always the same error, swapping out the **Float** part with whatever type it's expecting.

Final note, the actual JSON field from the response object reads as follows:

```
isFutureDated = 0;
```

It's not a field that I'm going to use in this particular app, but if this problem is going to happen again I'd like to find a solution to it before it counts.

Comment: The comments for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826140/unable-to-decode-a-json-with-json-decoder might be helpful. Looks like you want `Bool`, not `Float`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, never mind. *isFutureDated* is supposed to be a boolean, not any kind of number. I.e.,

```
let isFutureDated: Bool?
```

Weird.

Comment: The name is a bit of a hint.

Comment: Yeah... for some reason I was thinking the value would be the number of days or seconds or something until the future date... yeah that's on me :P thanks for the help!